# robocopy copy files to a new folder in the current folder without the new created folder

Tags: cmd, robocopy

i want to copy the WHOLE folder in a new subfolder. currently i am using:

```
(robocopy "C:/Test" "C:/Test/a" /E> output.log)  ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

after running this, there is in "C:/Test/a" also the "/a" folder. i dont want that new folder.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `&`? *Never* set `ErrorLevel`! to clear it use `ver > nul`.

Comment: please ignore that &. thats not the part of the question.

Comment: So why do you post this part then?? Anyway, it seems that `robocopy` does not like the destination folder to reside in the source folder; you could do `rmdir "C:\Test\a\a"` afterwards as a work-around. By the way, the Windows path separator is the `\ `but not the `/`!

Comment: Ha, there is a better way than deleting the unwanted directory afterwards: write `robocopy "C:\Test" "C:\Test\a" /E /XD "C:\Test\a"`, so the folder `a` is excluded to be (re-)copied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `robocopy` command seems to get confused when a full source directory tree is to be copied and the destination directory is located somewhere in the source directory tree. Therefore your command line results in a directory `C:\Test\a\a` that partially contains stuff from the source.

Try with the `/L` option (do not copy but list items that would be copied), so the output log shows exactly what you would expect. As soon as you actually do copy (so with `/L` removed), there are some more items listed in the log unexpectedly. This behaviour indicates that `robocopy` does not evaluate the whole source directory tree in advance, but during the actual copying operation.

The easiest way to avoid that is to exclude the destination directory from being (re-)copied:

```cmd
robocopy "C:\Test" "C:\Test\a" /E /XD "C:\Test\a"
```

By the way, the correct Windows path separator is the `\`. Although `robocopy` also accepts `/`, you should stick to `\`, because many commands do misinterpret the `/`.